# Android ownCloud Server Not Configured

Tags: android, owncloud

I'm getting some strange results trying to upload files to an ownCloud server on Android. Sometimes I get a log back that says "The ownCloud server is not configured!" and other times it works fine and gives me an HTTP status 204 (success) with the same server URL. Files get uploaded just fine so I'm curious why I'm getting this "not configured" message a lot. Here's my upload code:

```
for (File dataFile : dataDirectory.listFiles()) {
    uploadFile(dataFile, "text/plain", getString(R.string.server_address));
}

public void uploadFile(File fileToUpload, String mimeType, String directory) {
    UploadRemoteFileOperation uploadOperation = new UploadRemoteFileOperation(fileToUpload.getPath(),
            directory + "/" + fileToUpload.getName(), mimeType);
    uploadOperation.addDatatransferProgressListener((OnDatatransferProgressListener) owner);
    uploadOperation.execute(dataTransferClient, (OnRemoteOperationListener) owner, dataTransferHandler);
}
```

Edit: Here's part of a log:

```
07-08 11:18:44.076  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:45.274  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:46.634  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:47.449  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:48.891  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:49.215  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:49.217  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:51.849  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:52.215  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:56.912  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:58.218  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:58.538  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:18:59.005  Operation finished with HTTP status code 204 (success)
07-08 11:19:01.361  Operation finished with HTTP status code 204 (success)
07-08 11:19:03.442  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:05.849  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:06.917  Operation finished with HTTP status code 204 (success)
07-08 11:19:08.301  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:08.642  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:10.608  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:10.881  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:11.685  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:12.175  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:14.481  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:15.900  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:16.227  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:19.323  Operation finished with HTTP status code 204 (success)
07-08 11:19:19.696  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:19.698  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:20.458  The ownCloud server is not configured!
07-08 11:19:22.946  The ownCloud server is not configured!
```

Comment: Could it be that the server is getting overloaded by requests? I'm looping through 60-ish files sending upload requests. I'll try synchronizing file upload to have one at a time and report back

Comment: Synchronizing does not fix this.